# MongoDB set password with only knowing the hash

Tags: python, mongodb, passwords

is there any way to set the user password in MongoDB without knowing the password, but only knowing the (correctly) hashed value?

The reason is we want to implement a central system that sets new user passwords without the need to save the clear text/unencrypted password.

My Idea would be to have a root user that is allowed to edit the `admin` collection and to modify `system.users`

I can edit it, but how do I calculate the credentials? e.g. the `SCRAM-SHA-1` looks like:

```
{
    "iterationCount" : 10000,
    "salt" : "o.......N+..........==",
    "storedKey" : "1.....h/t...............FU=",
    "serverKey" : "k.........................b+10="
}
```

edit: i am using python and found [passlib](http://pythonhosted.org/passlib/lib/passlib.hash.scram.html) but what is here my `salt`, `storedKey` and `serverKey`

Comment: Have you looked into the *digestPassword* parameter in the [createUser](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/createUser/#dbcmd.createUser) method?

Comment: Looks like it May fit my needs but isn't documented. Still the question how can i generate Mongo compatible scram-sha-1 hashes?

Comment: MongoDB's own [procedure to create a user with SCRAM-SHA1 credentials](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/improved-password-based-authentication-mongodb-30-scram-explained-part-1?jmp=docs) looks pretty complicated; it's a four-step process of salting, calculating and hashing, so you're going to need to replicate that pretty closely.